# provideInlineCompletionItems method is triggered twice

Tags: vscode-extensions

When I stop typing in the editor, the provideInlineCompletionItems method is triggered twice: first with triggeredKind = 1, and then immediately again with triggeredKind = 0. According to the documentation: "If inline completions are enabled, this method will be called whenever the user stops typing."

That's okay. But why does it happen twice?

Is it a bug, or is the double triggering with different triggeredKind values part of the design of the inline completion feature? Should I build our extension's logic around this double triggering behavior?

My main problem is that if I return an empty array or undefined in response to the second (subsequent) request, it makes my suggestion widget in the editor empty. How can I see the result that was received on the first request with triggeredKind = 1? In other words, how can I prevent a second request without losing initial results and without cashing initial results ?

I use VS Code v 1.84.0
When I stop typing in the editor, the provideInlineCompletionItems method is triggered twice: first with triggeredKind = 1, and then immediately again with triggeredKind = 0.

I'm expecting just single triggering with triggeredKind = 1.

Answer (score 1):

I need to change the configuration of the launch.json file in the .vscode folder to following:

{
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [{
"name": "Run Extension",
"type": "extensionHost",
"request": "launch",
"runtimeExecutable": "${execPath}",
"args": [
"--user-data-dir=vscode-test",
"--extensionDevelopmentPath=${workspaceFolder}",
"--disable-extensions",
"--profile-temp",
],
"outFiles": [
"${workspaceFolder}/out/**/*.js"
],
"preLaunchTask": "npm: watch"
}
]
}

Question about inline completion provider · Issue #182587 · microsoft/vscode